# Send-MailMessage unable to pass -attachment variable

Tags: powershell, email-attachments

I'm trying to run the following script. It works fine until it gets to the `-attachment` option.

```
$Log = "c:\logs\%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%.log"
Send-MailMessage -From "helpdesk@myco.com" -to "my@myco.com" -Subject "test log" -Body "test body" -Smtpserver "mailserver.com" -port "25" -attachment $Log
```

Comment: That's a funky looking $Log variable.  Did you put a Write-Host or Write-Verbose in there when running it to see if the $Log variable contains the file path you think it contains?

Comment: To @adbertram's point, is the attachment really named `c:\logs\%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%.log` ?  Because this is what PowerShell thinks the name is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell can't use batch variables (that's what `%something%` is). In PowerShell you get the current date in ISO format like this:

```
Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

So your code should probably look like this:

```
$Log = "C:\logs\$(Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd).log"
Send-MailMessage -From "helpdesk@myco.com" -to "my@myco.com" -Subject ...
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. Here is what I ended up doing.
$date = get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd
$log = "c:\logs\$date" + ".log"
Send-MailMessage -From "helpdesk@myco.com" -to "myemail@myco.com" -Subject "Backup Log for helpdesk on $date" -Body (Get-Content $log) -Smtpserver "mailserver.com" -port "25" -attachment $log